# PHP checkbox is checked take textbox value

Tags: php, arrays, email

Hi im trying to make a mail system that takes the value of textbox that have checkedtextboxes but i cant seem to get it working and have no idea left how to do it so i have no code at all.

I know you need to make an foreach array loop but i just cant seem to get it working.
here is the table i want it to take from.

```
    echo'<table>
    <tr><th></th><th>Artikelnummer:</th><th>Produkt:</th><th>Kvantitet per enhet:</th><th>Producent:</th><th>Antal:</th></tr>';
    while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
        echo"<tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='produkt[]' value='".$arr['fldId']."'></td>
        <td>".$arr['fldArtNr']."</td>
        <td>".$arr['fldName']."</td>
        <td>".$arr['fldGross']."</td>
        <td>".$arr['fldProducer']."</td>
        <td><input type='text' size='4' name='t".$arr['fldId']."'></td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo'</table>';
```

Comment: Just as a heads up, the mysql_* family of functions are considered [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php), and shouldn't be used in new code.

Comment: That is just displaying stuff from the database. Once this displays then people click your checkboxes and write in your textbox, THEN you submit a form presumably and that's when your code comes in. This code is like 2 steps behind.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try the code, but i think it's something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['produkt'] as $val) {
    echo $_POST['t'.$val];
}
```

Stefan.